# fetch substring from a string using regex

Tags: regex

I want to fetch 01-01-2019 from Ram~01-01-2019 using regex. Can someone help?

I have a table in sql where two columns are present id and data. In data column, Ram~01-01-2019 -- this kind of data is getting stored from which I want to fetch dates only.

Comment: `\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}`?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe,

```
(?<=~)\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}
```

might be close.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/NOJKGC/1/)

or without lookarounds,

```
[^~\r\n]*~(\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4})
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/gNn6NN/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex to extract date only which have this kind of format **dd-dd-dddd**

```
\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{4}
```